# fs.watch events and websockets, catching "no-change" situations

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, fs

I watch a file with:

```
fs.watch('./data/object.json', (eventType, filename) => {})
    if (`${eventType}` === 'change'){
        // I call my emission function.
        emission(/* passing the contents of the file here */);
    })
```

This is what the emission function is:

```
// Just a dummy place-holder function.
// We later replace that with the real function inside the websocket
// block.
var emitter = function() {};

// Define a hook for the emission point.¬
// 'input' is the bit that receives the contents of the file.
var emission = function(input) {
    emitter(input);
};
```

I do this, cause I later inject the function in a websocket call:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    emitter = function(input){
        // This receives the contents of the file through the input.
        // Do some more stuff, convert 'input' into 'data'...
        // ... and send to the client.
        wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
            client.send(data);
        }
    }
});
```

So I swap the dummy emitter function with a real one while inside the websocket connection block.

Although a bit convoluted, this is working so far. I get a real-time constant stream to the client as the contents of the file change.

My problem is: I cannot catch the event of the contents of the file not changing anymore. I need to be able to catch that and let the client know that the file is not changing anymore.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Isn't `\`${eventType}\` === 'change'` just a really elaborate way of writing `eventType === 'change'`? Also, how would `fs.watch` know that a file is not changing anymore? You probably have to emit such an event yourself if, after X amount of time, the file hasn't changed.

Comment: Good point. I have based my code on this example: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher How to wrap the watch function inside another function that can emit custom events? In my case, `noChange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fs.watch` callback simply create a timer to periodically check if the file is changing.

```
var changing = false;
var timer = null; 

function checkChanging() {
    if (!changing) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;

      notifyNoChange();
    }
    changing = false;
}

fs.watch('./data/object.json', (eventType, filename) => {})
    if (`${eventType}` === 'change'){
        if (!timer ) {
            timer = setInterval(checkChanging, 1000);
        }

        changing = true;

        // I call my emission function.
        emission(/* passing the contents of the file here */);
    })
```

The timer is set the first time the file begins to change. You may need to refactor this code if you want to handle the situation where the file doesn't begin to change at all.
The `checkChanging` function will check if there has been a file change within the last second, and call a `notifyNoChange` function (that you need to implement).

Comment: Thank you. I will test your solution. Would it be a good idea to wrap both functions in one single function with closures? I would like to avoid using global variables?

Comment: yes, reorganize the code however you see fit, I just presented the general idea